# How to export template instantiation as non weak?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, elf, icc

C++ template functions are exported as weak symbols to work around the one definition rule ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58241873/why-are-functions-generated-on-use-of-template-have-weak-as-symbol-type)). In a situation where the function is explicitly instantiated for every use case, is there a way to export the symbol as non-weak?

Example use case:

```
// foo.hpp
template<typename T>
void foo();

// All allowed instantiations are explicitly listed.
extern template void foo<int>();
extern template void foo<short>();
extern template void foo<char>();
```

```
// foo.cpp
template<typename T>
void foo()
{
  // actual implementation
}

// All explicit instantiations.
template void foo<int>();
template void foo<short>();
template void foo<char>();
```

When I compile the code above with GCC or ICC, they are tagged as weak:

```
$ nm foo.o
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
0000000000000000 W _Z3fooIcEvv
0000000000000000 W _Z3fooIiEvv
0000000000000000 W _Z3fooIsEvv
```

Is there a way to prevent that? Since they are actually definitive, I would want them to not be candidate for replacement.

Comment: Why would you expect other instantiations to differ? In situations like this, the idea is that it doesn't matter that symbols are weak, because all have the same definitions.

Comment: **Weak** does not mean "candidate for replacement".  It means the same exact candidate, of which any one of them is as good as any other of them, because they are identical.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? Why do you prevent it?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I agree that it does not matter for the final binary. As far as I can tell `weak` means that the symbol can be switched with another symbol of the same name during link; not necessary the same implementation. It is used with templates to avoid ODR violation because template instantiations tend to appear in many object files. The problem I am trying to solve is that the link time is too slow and I want to reduce the work of the linker to the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objcopy` supports the `--weaken` option, but you want the opposite.

It also supports the `--globalize-symbol`, but that appears to have no effect on weak symbols:

```
gcc -c t.cc
readelf -Ws t.o | grep _Z3fooI

    14: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    7 _Z3fooIiEvv
    15: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    8 _Z3fooIsEvv
    16: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    9 _Z3fooIcEvv

objcopy -w --globalize-symbol _Z3fooI* t.o t1.o && 
readelf -Ws t1.o | grep _Z3fooI

    14: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    7 _Z3fooIiEvv
    15: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    8 _Z3fooIsEvv
    16: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT    9 _Z3fooIcEvv
```

Not to be deterred, we can first localize the symbols, then globalize them:

```
objcopy -w -L _Z3fooI* t.o t1.o &&
objcopy -w --globalize-symbol _Z3fooI* t1.o t2.o &&
readelf -Ws t2.o | grep _Z3fooI

    14: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    7 _Z3fooIiEvv
    15: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    8 _Z3fooIsEvv
    16: 0000000000000000     7 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    9 _Z3fooIcEvv
```

Voilà: the symbols are now strongly defined.

> The problem I am trying to solve is that the link time is too slow and I want to reduce the work of the linker to the minimum.

If this makes the linker do less work (which I doubt), I'd consider that a bug in the linker -- if the symbol is defined once, it shouldn't matter to the linker whether that definition is strong or weak.

Comment: After doing some benchmarks, I do not see any difference indeed in the link duration when switching from weak to strong symbols :)